# How do I stop XCode from automatically adding imports in new files?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

How can I stop XCode from automatically adding imports to the top of new files?

For example, if I create a new class that is a subclass of a UIKit class, the UIKit header is automatically added to the top of my header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

And likewise, if I create a new class that is a subclass of a Foundation class, the Foundation head is automatically added to the top of my header.

I'm using XCode 5.0.2.

Comment: Create your own templates.

Comment: Don't tell it you're creating a subclass.

Comment: why you don't want the import?

Comment: Put them all in my pch file

Comment: Precompiled header files are gone from Xcode 6 templates for good reasons. Why does a simple import statement at the top of the file bother you so much?